# Return len of the longest word in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, maxlength

Hi, I'm trying to make an python program that will return the length of the longest word in a list but it does not work so well for me.

here is the code:

```
def find_longest_word():
   list1 = ['a','aa','aaa','aaaa','aaaaa','aaaaaa','aaaaaaa','aaaaaaaa',]
   max1 = ''
   for x in range (0, len(list1)):
      if (len(max1) < len(list1[x]) ):
          max1 = list1[x]
   return max1    


def main():
    m = find_longest_word()
    print len(m)
```

Comment: Is this how your actual script is indented?

Comment: So what's the problem? What happens when you run it? Don't say "it doesn't work"!

Comment: What actually happens? "it does not work so well" is very vague; for all we know, it could be working fine, and you might just want it to work better.

Comment: Did you forget to call `main`? It won't get called automatically; you need to put in an explicit call.

Comment: `return max1` needs to be tabbed to the right, and you need to call main as `main()` somewhere.  Whitespace matters in python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, your problem is quite simple: you forgot to call the `main` function at the end of your script:

```
main()
```

When you do, it prints `8`, just like it should.

---

However, you can accomplish this task a lot easier if you use [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#max) and its [key function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#key-function):

```
>>> list1 = ['a','aa','aaa','aaaa','aaaaa','aaaaaa','aaaaaaa','aaaaaaaa',]
>>> max(list1, key=len)
'aaaaaaaa'
>>> len(max(list1, key=len))
8
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

While my above solution works fine, I want to offer an even shorter one I just thought of:

```
>>> list1 = ['a','aa','aaa','aaaa','aaaaa','aaaaaa','aaaaaaa','aaaaaaaa',]
>>> max(map(len, list1))
8
>>>
```

Instead of a key function, this solution uses [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: oh. thank you but can you tell me what not working in my code?
im trying not to use in "built in ready" functions

Comment: @RomBecker - Well, since you didn't include a traceback, give me one sec to run your code.   Also, `len` and `range`, which you use, are "built in ready functions".

Comment: oh lol i have forgoten to call the main() funtion ....
thank you

Comment: @Downvoter - Did you find something wrong with my post?  Please, let me know what it is so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
mx=0
for word in list1:
    if len(word)>mx:
        mx=len(word)
#now max will contain the length of longest word
```

Edit: This might not be the ideal answer, but the intention was to give code which is similar to the code in question.

Comment: Why start max at 1000? What if the longest word in the list is shorter than 1000 letters?

Comment: Please don't use max as a variable, this should be only for the function max.

Comment: @StephenTG , ohh. I should have initialized it to zero instead. My bad. Anyway, edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_longest_word():
    list1 = ['a','aa','aaa','aaaa','aaaaa','aaaaaa','aaaaaaa','aaaaaaaa',]  # this should be a parameter
    max1 = ''
    for x in range (0, len(list1)):  # you don't have to include 0 in this
        if (len(max1) < len(list1[x]) ): 
            max1 = list1[x]
    return max1    


def main():
    m = find_longest_word()
    print len(m)
```

Your indentation was wrong, although that could be formatting from pasting it here. A simpler way that has the same structure as you function:

```
def find_longest_word(lst):
    max1 = ''
    for x in lst:
        if (len(x) > len(max1)): 
            max1 = x
    return max1    


def main():
    m = find_longest_word()
    print len(m)
```

Comment: You need to get your return out of your for loop. As it is, this won't return the right value

Answer (score -2):

with a sorted reverse you can get longest string too

```
sorted(list1,key=len,reverse=True)[0]
'aaaaaaaa'
```

Comment: Sorting a list is expensive and the code is less readable than with max

Comment: This is both inefficient and bugged. You're sorting by lexicographic order, rather than length.

Comment: you can use __len__ function for cmp attribute too

Comment: oh lol i have forgoten to call the main() funtion ....
thank you guys

Comment: sorted(list1,key=len,reverse=True)[0]

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this:

'''Write a function find_longest_word() that takes a list of words and
returns the length of the longest one.'''

```
a = ['mamao', 'abacate', 'pera', 'goiaba', 'uva', 'abacaxi', 'laranja', 'maca']

def find_longest_word(a):

    d = []
    for c in a:
        d.append(len(c))
        e = max(d)  #Try "min" :D
    for b in a:
        if len(b) == e:
            print "Length is %i for %s" %(len(b), b)
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer in multiple places. Flag the question as duplicate instead.